# What's wrong with my first 'c' bubble sort programme?

Tags: c

I just want to know what is the wrong with it, and how to fix it.

It looks like every thing is right, but when you run the .exe it crash every time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// first list filling function:

void  T_filling(int T[],int n){
    int i;
    for(i=1 ;i<=n ;i++){
        printf("enter the number:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&T[i]);
    }
}

//then the main algorithm:

int main()
{
    int j,k,l;
    int n,x;
    // you can order up to 100 integer number

    int T[100];
    printf("This program is to order numbers decreasingly\n");
    printf("how many numbers you want to order?\n");

    // scanning the number of elements in the list

    scanf(n);
    //filling the list
    T_filling(T[100],n);
    //bubble sort Algorithm
    for(j=1;j<=n-1;j++){
        for(k=1;k<=n-j;k++){
            if(T[k+1]>T[k]){
                x=T[k];
                T[k]=T[k+1];
                T[k+1]=x;
            }
        }
    }
    for(l=1;l<=n;l++){
        //printing the result on screen
        printf("%d;",T[l]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First off - what makes you think anything is wrong with it? By not providing such an important detail.... a description of what should happen and what is happening instead, you deprive yourself of potential answers because people will just move on. Second, a brief code scan reveals that you seem unaware that a C array is indexed beginning at 0 not 1, so all your `for` loops such as `for(l=1` are skipping the first element (and might be using an element beyond the end of the valid buffer).

Comment: it was purposed to skip the first element ,the max number of element to order is 100 not 101, the 0 element skipped in the entire Algorithm

Comment: When you declare `T[100]`, your valid elements are indexes 0 through 99. Therefore you only have 100 elements and you must start with 0.

Comment: Thank's for the information

Comment: I would strongly suggest checking return value of `scanf`... If you don't, with bad luck you'll get really weird behaviour with invalid input, and then you waste time trying to find bugs that actually aren't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `scanf` and passing the `array` to `function` properly.

Please modify these lines in your code as follows and your program will work as expected.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
//filling the list
while(n > 100)
{
    printf("Exceeding size, please re enter the size");
    scanf("%d", &n);
}
T_filling(T,n);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note also that it would probably be a good idea to make sure `n` is not larger than the maximum size of the buffer, nor is it <= 0.

Comment: It was a huge mistake, i changed it but still these three errors : 
passing argument 1 of 'T_filling' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] and 
too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args] and 
expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'

Comment: @mah yeah, your are right, i will update the answer

Comment: @YounesReddler what three error?

Comment: I worked now Sudipta Kumar Sahoo, Thank's for helping !!!!